# SQL query for getting total hours worked and overtime in one query - resulting in resultset with data for all users

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get total hours and total overtime for a given period of time, for all users. I have managed to build a query that will give the desired result, but for a specific user decided by id only.

```
SELECT 
    navn AS name, 
    hour AS hoursTotal, 
    overTime as overtimeTotal 
FROM ( 
    SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttid, sluttid)) AS hour
    FROM hours 
    WHERE hours.user_id = 14 
    AND DATE(starttid) BETWEEN '2018-8-25' AND '2018-9-25'
    ) AS T,
    (
    SELECT SUM( IF( TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttid, sluttid) >= TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000') , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttid, sluttid) - TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000') , 0 ) ) AS overTime
    FROM hours 
    WHERE user_id = 14 
    AND DATE(starttid) BETWEEN '2018-8-25' AND '2018-9-25' 
    ) AS O,
    (
    SELECT name AS navn 
    FROM users
    WHERE users.id = 14 
    ) AS F
```

This gives me:

```
name       | hoursTotal  | overtimeTotal
John Doe   | 245700      | 85860
```

John Doe has user.id 14

I cannot get my head around getting this result, but for all users in the period 2018-8-25 to 2018-9-25

Desired Result:

```
name       | hoursTotal  | overtimeTotal
John Doe   | 245700      | 85860
Jane Doe   | 354664      | 78243
Tarzan     | 203111      | 0
Batman     | 100233      | 0
```

I am hoping someone can help me in the right direction here.

Comment: You need to move away from implicit joins. You should also provide us table structure, sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be you need  a sum and group by with join

```
    SELECT users.name AS name, 
        SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttid, sluttid)) AS hoursTotal, 
        SUM( IF( TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttid, sluttid) >= TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000') , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttid, sluttid) - TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000') , 0 ) ) as overtimeTotal 
        FROM hours 
        INNER JOIN users on hours.user_id = users.id
        WHERE DATE(starttid) BETWEEN '2018-8-25' AND '2018-9-25'
    group by users.name
```

Comment: Thank YOU for this - i will now sit down and study this in depth - as you probably could see, im no pro at this. I have been using hours watching tutorials on sql, but still - i might have stuck my brain in a wrong way :D

Just needed to fix syntax - the AND in where clause :)